# Are a (co)tangent vector's "coordinate components" equivalent to the "coordinate components of its pushfoward to R^n"?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces, diffeomorphism

[All equation numbers reference *Wald, Robert M.*, [**General relativity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.7208/chicago/9780226870373.001.0001), Chicago-London: The University of Chicago Press. XIII, 491 p. 34.50 (1984).]

Consider a subset $O$ of an $n$-dimensional, $C^{\infty}$, real manifold $M$.  Let $\psi:O\to V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a chart and let $x^\mu:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ denote coordinates corresponding to some choice of basis $\{e_\mu\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Composition yields the smooth maps $x^\mu\circ \psi:O\to\mathbb{R}$.

Now, the corresponding coordinate components $v^\mu$ of any tangent vector $v\in V_p$ at $p\in O$ are given by
\begin{align}
v^\mu=v(x^\mu\circ\psi(p)), \tag{2.2.6}\label{v mu}
\end{align}
with $v(f)$ viewed as a linear map $v:C^{\infty}(M)\to\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, the push-forward map $\psi^*:V_p\to V_{\psi(p)}$ associated with $\psi$ is defined via
\begin{align}
(\psi^*v)(f)\equiv v(f\circ\psi) \tag{C.1.1}\label{push v},
\end{align}
for all smooth $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.  So, it would seem the coordinate components of $\psi^*v$ at $\psi(p)$ are given by the same expression as the coordinate components of $v$ at $p$:

\begin{align}
(\psi^*v)^\mu = (\psi^*v)(x^\mu) \overset{\eqref{push v}}{=} v(x^\mu\circ\psi(p)) \overset{\eqref{v mu}}{=}v^\mu \label{*}\tag{$\star$}
\end{align}

Likewise, in the basis dual to \begin{align}X_\mu(f)\equiv \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}(f\circ \psi^{-1})\right|_{\psi(p)} \tag{2.2.1} \label{X mu},
\end{align}
the coordinate components of any dual vector $w\in {V}^*_p$ are given by
\begin{align}
w_\mu=w(X_\mu), \tag{c.f. Ch2 Problem 6.b} \label{w mu}
\end{align}
Since $\psi$ is bijective, its inverse ${\psi^{-1}}:V\to O$ can provide a push-forward $(\psi^{-1})^*:{V}^*_p \to {V}^*_{\psi(p)}$ for cotangent vectors by requiring that for every $v\in V_{\psi (p)}$,
\begin{align}
((\psi^{-1})^*w)(v)=w((\psi^{-1})^*v) \tag{c.f. C.1.2} \label{push w}
\end{align}
The coordinate components of $(\psi^{-1})^*w$ at $\psi(p)$ are given by,
\begin{align}
((\psi^{-1})^*w)_\mu = ((\psi^{-1})^*w)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \right) \overset{\eqref{push w}}{=} w\left((\psi^{-1})^*\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right)\overset{\eqref{X mu}}{=}w(X_\mu)\overset{\eqref{w mu}}{=}w_\mu. \label{**}\tag{$\star\star$}
\end{align}

Since tensors at $p$ are defined as multilinear maps over $V_p$ and ${V}^*_p$, one should straightforwardly obtain analogous formulas for tensors of any type using $\eqref{*}$ and $\eqref{**}$.

**Question(s):** Are formulas \eqref{*} and \eqref{**} and their derivations correct? Is it valid to view these formulas as saying: "*The coordinate components (associated with chart $\psi$) of a tensor at $p\in M$ are equal the coordinate components of the tensor's push-forward via $\psi$ to $\psi(p)\in\mathbb{R}^n$*" ?

Comment: A push-forward map should *not* be notated with an upper star; that denotes a pullback. In mathematics, we use lower stars for the derivative pushing forward.

Comment: @TedShifrin I appreciate the remark on conventions.  Since I was referencing Wald's text, I tried to be consistent with his notation in Appendix C.  Wald is a physicist, so perhaps this explains his unconventional notation?

Comment: Physicists often use abhorrent notation, yes. :) This is particularly heinous since we *do* all pull back differential forms (in particular, cotangent vectors).